# SwiftUI Infinite Scroll with deleting items at the beginning of list

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to build an infinite scroll list and I want to delete items at the beginning of the list when scrolling. (I need a truly infinite list)

On the internet i found many solutions but nether one of them wasn't deleting items at the beginning of the list. I tried a lot of things but in every one of them there is full rerender of the list. I want everything to be smooth.

```
ZStack{
                LazyVStack(spacing: 0){
                    
                    ForEach(0..<test.count, id: \.self) {index in
                       
                        ZStack{
                            Text("\(list[index])")
                                .textStyle(color: .black)
                          
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .frame(height: 100)
                        .border(.green)
                        .id(index)


                    }
                }
}
```

I Have this setup. I can add to the list and everything is smooth and ok but when i delete from the beginning and add to the end of the list the scroll is not resetting like an in infinite scroll.